# Populating field options from a different field in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following four classes:

```
class Subject(Sortable):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hebrew_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=6)

class Category(Sortable):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hebrew_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Subject = SortableForeignKey(Subject)

class Subcategory(Sortable):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hebrew_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Category = SortableForeignKey(Category)

class Summary(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    content = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Basically Subjects contain categories, categories contain sub-categories, and each summary is associated with one of each.

Currently the relationship between the fields in the Summary class isn't related to the relationship between the Subjects Categories and Subcategories.

What I want is basically to be able to create a form that you must first choose a subject (for example from a dropdown) and only then is the next dropdown populated from the categories within that subject, after choosing a category the same should then happen with the subcategories..

I want this to be enforceable at the highest level possible, If i can make this at the database level that would be ideal.

Obviously if a summary is under the subject Literature it cannot be part of the Category "the rise of nationalism" which is a category under history for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't doing this at the database level. The relations between your models are fine, but the database doesn't care what a "Litterature" category is or whatever. The architecture enforces the integrity of data architecture, i.e, a subcategory has only one category. Then, it's up to you to enforce the integrity of content.

So for your specific problematic, I think you're best bet is handling the form via Ajax. You could setup a form with the fields you want, and populate these fields via Ajax, on select callback from above field.

When user validates the form, it's up to you to perform a custom validation (in the clean method of your form), testing the integrity of data and raising custom error if needed.

Let met know if you want a more detailed answer with form + view + js part.

Comment: I don't really have my grips around Ajax yet, I understand javascript syntax though so a bone in the right direction would go along way, thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure, can you give more details about your Summary model ? Is a summary object unique to a couple (category, subcategory) ? i.e, there is a summary for (categoryA, subcategory1), a different summary for (categoryA,subcategory2), a different on for (categoryB, subcategory1), etc. ?

Comment: The website is for school material, a summary has a subject, category, subcategory, but they can have many summaries.

eg: Subject "Literature">Category "Short Stories">Subcategory "20th century science fiction short stories" > many summaries

Comment: no, a sub category can be part of one category and a category can be part of one subject

Comment: Ok, so you're architecture is not the best. You should take a took to django-categories : http://django-categories.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: Any tips on improving it without using 3rd party plugins?